# How to iterate thorugh a collection of lists to call a function in R?

Tags: r

I have the following lists in R:

```
logFramesChartInfo <- list(columnName="quality_logframes_overall", guageChartTitle="Logframes", guageChartId="logframes_quality", histogramChartTitle="Logframes Quality")
indicatorsChartInfo <- list(columnName="quality_indicators_overall", guageChartTitle="Logframes", guageChartId="indicators_quality", histogramChartTitle="Indicators Quality")
```

I would like to call a function with each of them, and to reduce code redundancy I would like to use a loop to do this, e.g.

```
chartInfos <- list("logFramesChartInfo" = logFramesChartInfo, "indicatorsChartInfo" = indicatorsChartInfo)
for (key in ChartInfos) {
   myFunction(chartInfos[key])
}
```

To test this out, I use the following:

```
myFunction(chartInfos["logFramesChartInfo"])
```

This doesn't work - I am running this as part of an R Shiny application, and I don't get an error, rather the chart doesn't display.

If, however, I call my function using the `logFramesChartInfo` variable I defined above:

```
myFunction(logFramesChartInfo)
```

The chart displays.

So right now to display multiple charts, I have to make multiple calls as follows:

```
myFunction(logFramesChartInfo)
myFunction(indicatorsChartInfo)
...
```

How can I iterate over all of the `chartInfo`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to use `[[` instead of `[` to move down a level in the list. Your function is getting a list of length 1 and it doesn't know what to do with it. Compare:

```r
length(chartInfos["logFramesChartInfo"])
# [1] 1

length(chartInfos[["logFramesChartInfo"]])
# [1] 4
```

You can read about the difference between the index operators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169495/10191355).